# Is this the FFT matrix

Tags: matrices

I read a paper that said that the K point FFT matrix is the following

[image]

Is that correct or should the elements be more like $$e^{-j 2\pi/K}$$

i.e, isnt the minus sign missing?

Also does anyone know of any important properties of this matrix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Asked simultaneously on dsp.SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/22528/235) and perhaps on other sites too.

Comment: That is correct, I did because I don't know where to put this question @DilipSarwate P.S if this is against the rules, I can delete one of them, no big deal. :)

Comment: @Tyrone I think it's best to focus on just one site at a time.

Comment: thanks is a question like this better in the signal processing form?

Comment: @DilipSarwate what is your problem, do you spend time looking for duplicated off two different sites? Maybe we are desperate for answer and we seek to learn and by doing so you are limiting our chances.